# Banking Menu Project using Class

Tags: c++, class

So we're learning about class in out c++ class, and to use it in a banking menu project. However, when I finished putting it together, I got error C3867. 'BankAccount::deposit': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member.

```
class BankAccount
{
private:
    string name;
    double balance;
public:
    BankAccount();
    double getBalance();
    bool deposit(double amt);
};
BankAccount::BankAccount()
    : name("John Doe"), balance(100)
{
}

double BankAccount::getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}

bool BankAccount::deposit(double amt)
{
    cout << "Enter Amount to Deposit: ";
    cin >> amt;
    if (amt > 0)
    {
        cout << "Success" << endl;
        balance = balance + amt;
        cout << "New Balance is: " << balance << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid Transaction" << endl;
    }
}   

int main()
{
    char choice;
    BankAccount JohnDoe;

    do
    {
        cout << "A. Deposit" << endl;
        cout << "Q. Quit" << endl;
        cout << "Please Make a Choice: " << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        switch (toupper(choice))
        {
        case 'A':
            JohnDoe.deposit;
            break;
        case'Q':
            cout << "Thank You For Using Our Services Today!" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Not a Valid Choice" << endl;
        }

    } while (toupper(choice) != 'Q');
```

Answer (score 0):

This function `bool BankAccount::deposit(double amt)` must return a bool value. Also, the function must accept parameter when you call it as in this line `JohnDoe.deposit;` which it should be `JohnDoe.deposit(<pass double value>);`